# How can I randomly generate the elements of a division a/b=c where c only has one decimal?

Tags: php, javascript, math

This is more of a basic math/programming question. I need to generate a division a/b=c. I will give the user a and b and he has to answer c, but c can only have one decimal. For example, c=5.2 is okay but 5.23 is too much to ask, because the users are children. So I need an algorithm that can generate randomly a division of this kind from all possible combinations where a has to be less than x, b has to be less than y, and c can only have one decimal. Also, a and b have to be integers.

I'm looking for a more elegant solution than trying numbers and checking them until a right combinations is produced. Also, this is for web content, so I'd prefer to do it with javascript, but it can be done in php if necesary. ¿Does some one know how could I do it? I'm not that good at maths.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Any other restrictions, like the answer should be greater than 1?   Or could 0.3 be acceptable?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I forgot to mention that. Operands have to be integers.

Comment: It's probably going to be easier to move the equation around a bit and work with c * b = a, provide the program with a random c and b within a bounds and get your a.

Comment: Do you want there to usually be a decimal, or occasionally be a decimal, or always be a decimal?  One possible simplistic implementation might have a decimal in three out of four tries.  Would that be appropriate?

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I could get c*b=a, then try all posible decimal numbers, from 0.0 to 0.9 and multiply those with b. Then randomly choose one of the results that give an integer and add that integer to a. The problem with that solution is that it still has to try numbers until a correct one is found. Even if that's better than just trying a lot of combinations until a right one is found, I'd like to know if a more elegant solutino is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try generate `C` as `int/10`.
Then generate `B`:

- just int if `(10 * C) % 10 == 0`
- `int * 2` if `(10 * C) % 5 == 0`
- `int * 5` if `(10 * C) % 2 == 0`
- `int * 10` else

Then `A = B * C` and it is int

PseudoCode:

```
tenC = rnd();
if(tenC % 10 == 0) B = rnd();
elseif(tenC % 5 == 0) B = rnd() * 2;
elseif(tenC % 2 == 0) B = rnd() * 5;
else B = rnd() * 10;
C = tenC / 10.0;
A = tenC * B / 10;
```

where rnd() generates integer as you like

Comment: The problem with that is that a has to be an integer. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @OscarAbraham, It will be integer, if you will generate it as follows (I hope you understand what is % operator)

Comment: I understand %. I think where I'm having trouble understanding is the int part. Could you explain it to me or put it in code form, please?

Comment: I understand now! Brilliant! it doesn't consider limits but is so elegant. So .0, .1, .2 and .5 are the only numbers that multiplied by a number that isn't a multiple of them and 10 give an integer. I never thought of that! I think the fifth line would be "else B= tenc*10;" wouldn't it? Can I edit it?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Any B that divides to 10 is OK. So we get it by random

Comment: Of course! Thank yo very much. I didn't see it, it is obvious now. one decimal is always an integer when multiplied with a multiple of ten.

Answer (score 2):

Basically we create a list with all of A * 10's prime factors, and then choose a random combination of factors to create B.

```
        int[] primes = new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997 };
        List<int> factors = new List<int>();
        int x = 1000;
        int y = 650;
        Random rand = new Random();
        int a = rand.Next(x);
        int _a = a * 10;
        int currentPrime = 0;

        //find all factors of a * 10
        while (_a > 1)
        {
            while (_a % primes[currentPrime] == 0)
            {
                factors.Add(primes[currentPrime]);
                _a /= primes[currentPrime];
            }
            currentPrime++;
        }

        int b = 1;
        foreach(int factor in factors)
        {
            if (b * factor > y) break;
            if (rand.Next(2) == 0)
            {
                b *= factor;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know a lot of c#. What you are doing with x and y is generate a limit for a random number?

Comment: You say "I don't know if it is mathematically correct", It is definitely correct. You need `b` that is divisor of `10 * a` and you got it.

Comment: No I really said "What you are doing with x and y is generate a limit for a random number?" So I could understand and translate the code to javascript. Any way, I think I kind of understand it, it still has to try numbers to get the correct factors. A more elegant solution has already been posted. But thank you, I really appreciat it.

Comment: Made it a little shorter, inspired by RiaD's comment.

Comment: @Oscar It doesn't have to try numbers, it just loops over the factors and randomly decides to include them or not by choosing a random number 0 or 1.

Comment: Oh I think I get it, I forgot my math classes and the process to get factors. You try factors and divide a number until that number is divisible by the number you want. I get it, sorry. I like your answer, I just think the other one is better because this still has to loop trough an array to get the factors list. Also, it stops at the minimum number. So if a number is divisible by 2, it doesn't try more.

Comment: Yes, but that will always be a bounded operation that will run in O(log n). By trying numbers I meant trying random numbers until a valid combination is found, which theoretically could run for ever.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Sorry if it seemed like I underestimated your answer, I didn't. I know it works. I just like better one that doesn't have to have an array from the start and then do a loop to get a and b. I know this is the most efficient way of doing it with a loop, because it gets the factors in a very elegant way.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Declare variables
var a, b, c, f = 1,
    highestCommonFactor = function(x, y) {
        var i;
        for (i = Math.min(x, y); i > 1; i--) {
            if (x / i == Math.round(x / i) && y / i == Math.round(y / i)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return false;
    };

// Pick two random numbers, b and c
// b should be a fairly small integer, i'll choose 5 as an upper limit
// c should be larger than 10 and not end with a 0
b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
do {
    c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
} while (c.toString().slice(-1) == "0");

// Multiply b by 10
b *= 10;

// Get a value for a
a = (c * b) / 10;

// Divide c by 10
c /= 10;

// Optional - Cancel a and b down to lowest possible integers
/*
while (f !== false) {
    a /= f;
    b /= f;
    f = highestCommonFactor(a, b);
}
//*/
```

Nothing like a good maths challenge to keep you awake. This code has a tendency to produce `a` and `b` where one of them is a multiple of 10, even if you uncomment the *Optional - Cancel down to lowest possible integers* section (`b` will always be multiple of 10 if you don't). However I think this is in the nature of what you are doing, since in order for `c` to have exactly 1 non-zero digit after the decimal point, it must be expressible as `int / 10`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ukq5r/2/)

Comment: Ha. I know, right? A soulution that doesn't have to try number combinations (even for a highest common factor) has been posted already. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
function findEquation($maxA, $maxB){
    $x = 2;
    $e = NULL;

    do {
        $a = rand(1, $maxA);
        $b = rand(1, $maxB);
        $e = "$a / $b";
        $y = explode(".", $a/$b);
        if(count($y) > 1){
            $x = strlen($y[1]);
        }else {
            $x = 0;
        }
    } while($x > 1);

    return $e;
}

echo findEquation(100,100);
```

Better, this will find the first equation that has a decimal value length < 2.

JavaScript solution:

```
function findEquation(maxA, maxB){
    var x = 2;
    var e = '';
    var a,b,c,d;

    do {
        a = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxA+1);
        b = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxB+1);
        e = a + '/' + b;
        c = (a/b).toString().split(".");
        if(c.length > 1){
            x = c[1].length;
        }else {
            x = 0;
        }
    } while( x > 1 );

    return e;
}

alert(findEquation(100,100));
```

Comment: Sorry, like I said in the question, I'm looking for a more elgant solution than trying all possible combinations. Thank you, never the less.

Comment: @OscarAbraham Why not run this once on your machine and then store the combinations you like. Why do you want to do it in real-time?

Comment: See updated. Also Bart, Oscar prefers it to be done in JavaScript, but I happened to write it in PHP, which he said was a viable solution.

Comment: It could be done in javascript. I know I could do this only once. I already posted in the comments of this question a solution that could do this a little faster because it would only need to do an iteration ten times each time a division is requested instead of a huge iteration at the start and/or a huge array. But I'd like to know if there is a solution that doesn't need to try combinations. I think it could be done with logarithms and all that magic but I forgot all about calculus and I never knew much about it, anyway.

Comment: I don't see how you would get away without trying combinations.

Comment: Would you accept an answer in C#? It shouldn't be hard to translate to JavScript

Comment: Also I'd like to point out that, to check if it has only one decimal, you don't need to convert it to string. You could multiply it by 10 and then do x%1.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/eX7fM/2/

```
var upper = getRandomInt(2, 100);

var lower;
var answer = 0.99; // sentinel

while (!numberHasOneOrNoDecimals(answer)) {
    lower = getRandomInt(1, upper);
    answer = upper / lower;
}
```

This still involves some looping, but it is a little more elegant than pure brute force and much simpler to understand than a non-looping approach would be (prime factorization and all that jazz is beyond my math skill as well).

Comment: This doesn't seem to do what was being asked.

Comment: Yes, it is a little more elegant, it also leaves software to functions one would have to write, so it's more organized. But like I said in the question comments, I already have a solution that I posted that would only have to loop ten times. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't have to try combinations and select the one or the ones that work.